# In Drupal 7 how can I programmatically create a menu link to a view?

Tags: views, forms

I am trying to programmatically create a menu link to a view. The view already has a menu item but I basically need a shortcut to it in another menu location in a separate module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) in a custom module.

```
function yourmodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['duplicate-view-path'] = array(
        'title' => 'View Title',
        'page callback' => 'custom_render_view',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function custom_render_view() {
  $output = views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id = 'default');
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using code, I will simply create an alias. You can do it if you've Path module activate and if you go to `admin/config/search/path` (Drupal 7) you will be able to create an alias that then you can use in your another menu.